# Program type already present: android.support.v4.os.ResultReceiver$MyResultReceiver

Tags: android, refactoring, androidx

I'm refactoring an app to use androidx. I have struggled to get rid of all the libraries that do not support it. 
I thought I had removed all the libraries that use the support libraries but it looks like there is still something that is importing it.
I now get the error:

> AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Program type already present:
>   android.support.v4.os.ResultReceiver$MyResultReceiver","sources":[{}],"tool":"D8"}
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException:
>   com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Error while
>   merging dex archives:
>   /Users/name/myproject/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/532,
>   /Users/name/myproject/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/0.jar,
>   /Users/name/myproject/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/1.jar,
>
> ...
>
> /Users/name/myproject/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/530.jar,
>   /Users/name/myproject/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/531.jar
>   Learn how to resolve the issue at
>   https://developer.android.com/studio/build/dependencies#duplicate_classes.
>   Program type already present:
>   android.support.v4.os.ResultReceiver$MyResultReceiver     at
>   sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor377.newInstance(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.getThrowableException(ForkJoinTask.java:593)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.reportException(ForkJoinTask.java:677)
>   ...   at
>   org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:46)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>     at
>   org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) Learn how to resolve the
>   issue at
>   https://developer.android.com/studio/build/dependencies#duplicate_classes.
>   Program type already present:
>   android.support.v4.os.ResultReceiver$MyResultReceiver     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask$AdaptedCallable.exec(ForkJoinTask.java:1431)
>     at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:289)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1056)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1692)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:157)
>   Learn how to resolve the issue at
>   https://developer.android.com/studio/build/dependencies#duplicate_classes.
>   Program type already present:
>   android.support.v4.os.ResultReceiver$MyResultReceiver     at
>   com.android.builder.dexing.D8DexArchiveMerger.getExceptionToRethrow(D8DexArchiveMerger.java:129)
>     at
>   com.android.builder.dexing.D8DexArchiveMerger.mergeDexArchives(D8DexArchiveMerger.java:114)
>     at
>   com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.DexMergerTransformCallable.call(DexMergerTransformCallable.java:101)
>     at
>   com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.DexMergerTransformCallable.call(DexMergerTransformCallable.java:36)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask$AdaptedCallable.exec(ForkJoinTask.java:1424)
>     ... 4 more  at
>   com.android.tools.r8.utils.ExceptionUtils.withCompilationHandler(ExceptionUtils.java:71)
>     at
>   com.android.tools.r8.utils.ExceptionUtils.withD8CompilationHandler(ExceptionUtils.java:41)
>     at com.android.tools.r8.D8.run(D8.java:89)  at
>   com.android.builder.dexing.D8DexArchiveMerger.mergeDexArchives(D8DexArchiveMerger.java:112)
>     ... 7 more  at
>   com.android.tools.r8.utils.Reporter.failIfPendingErrors(Reporter.java:83)
>     at com.android.tools.r8.utils.Reporter.fatalError(Reporter.java:62)
>     at
>   com.android.tools.r8.utils.ExceptionUtils.withCompilationHandler(ExceptionUtils.java:62)
>     ... 10 more :app:transformDexArchiveWithDexMergerForDebug FAILED
>   FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>   * What went wrong: Execution failed for task ':app:transformDexArchiveWithDexMergerForDebug'.
>
> > com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException:
> >     com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Error while
> >     merging dex archives:
> >     /Users/name/myproject/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/532,
> >     /Users/name/myproject/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/0.jar,
> >     /Users/name/myproject/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/1.jar,
>
> ...
>
> /Users/name/myproject/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/530.jar,
>   /Users/name/myproject/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/531.jar
>   Learn how to resolve the issue at
>   https://developer.android.com/studio/build/dependencies#duplicate_classes.
>   Program type already present:
>   android.support.v4.os.ResultReceiver$MyResultReceiver

Running `./gradlew androidDependencies` and I get:

```
debugCompileClasspath - Dependencies for compilation
+--- io.realm:realm-android-library:5.1.0@aar
+--- io.realm:realm-android-kotlin-extensions:5.1.0@aar
+--- io.realm:realm-annotations:5.1.0@jar
+--- javax.annotation:jsr250-api:1.0@jar
+--- com.google.dagger:dagger-android:2.16@aar
+--- androidx.preference:preference:1.0.0-alpha1@aar
+--- com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0-alpha1@aar
+--- androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.0-alpha1@aar
+--- androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0-alpha1@aar
+--- androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.0.0-alpha1@aar
+--- androidx.gridlayout:gridlayout:1.0.0-alpha1@aar
+--- androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0-alpha1@aar
+--- androidx.vectordrawable:vectordrawable-animated:1.0.0-alpha1@aar
+--- androidx.vectordrawable:vectordrawable:1.0.0-alpha1@aar
+--- androidx.palette:palette:1.0.0-alpha1@aar
+--- com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:3.1.0@aar
+--- com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:15.0.0@aar
+--- com.google.firebase:firebase-config:15.0.2@aar
+--- com.google.firebase:firebase-database:15.0.1@aar
+--- com.jakewharton.rxbinding2:rxbinding:2.0.0@aar
+--- com.jakewharton.rxrelay2:rxrelay:2.0.0@jar
+--- joda-time:joda-time:2.5@jar
+--- com.jakewharton.timber:timber:4.3.1@aar
+--- com.uncopt:android.justified:1.0@jar
+--- androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-common-java8:2.0.0-alpha1@jar
+--- androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.0.0-alpha1@aar
+--- androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-reactivestreams:2.0.0-alpha1@aar
+--- com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava2:2.2.0@jar
+--- com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-moshi:2.2.0@jar
+--- com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-scalars:2.2.0@jar
+--- com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.2.0@jar
+--- com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp-urlconnection:3.4.1@jar
+--- com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.4.1@jar
+--- com.github.franmontiel:PersistentCookieJar:v1.0.1@aar
+--- com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.6.0@jar
+--- com.squareup.moshi:moshi-kotlin:1.5.0@jar
+--- com.github.MFlisar:RxBus2:0.1@aar
+--- com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.8.1@aar
+--- com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android:1.5.1@aar
+--- com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.6.8@aar
+--- com.f2prateek.rx.preferences2:rx-preferences:2.0.0-RC2@aar
+--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.2.41@jar
+--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-android-extensions-runtime:1.2.41@jar
+--- com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:1.3.9@jar
+--- com.getkeepsafe.relinker:relinker:1.2.2@aar
+--- com.google.dagger:dagger:2.16@jar
+--- com.android.support:customtabs:26.1.0@aar
+--- com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.1.0@aar
+--- com.jakewharton:butterknife-annotations:8.8.1@jar
+--- com.android.support:design:26.1.0@aar
+--- com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0@aar
+--- com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.1.0@aar
+--- com.android.support:transition:26.1.0@aar
+--- com.google.firebase:firebase-abt:15.0.1@aar
+--- com.google.firebase:firebase-database-connection:15.0.1@aar
+--- com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:15.0.2@aar
+--- com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-impl:15.0.2@aar
+--- com.google.firebase:firebase-iid:15.1.0@aar
+--- com.google.firebase:firebase-common:15.0.1@aar
+--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-phenotype:15.0.1@aar
+--- com.google.firebase:firebase-database-collection:15.0.1@aar
+--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:11.4.2@aar
+--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads-identifier:15.0.1@aar
+--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-stats:15.0.1@aar
+--- com.google.firebase:firebase-iid-interop:15.0.0@aar
+--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth-api-phone:11.4.2@aar
+--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth-base:11.4.2@aar
+--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-flags:15.0.1@aar
+--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:15.0.1@aar
+--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks:15.0.1@aar
+--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:15.0.1@aar
+--- com.android.support:support-v4:26.1.0@aar
+--- com.android.support:support-media-compat:26.1.0@aar
+--- com.android.support:support-fragment:26.1.0@aar
+--- com.android.support:support-core-utils:26.1.0@aar
+--- com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:26.1.0@aar
+--- com.android.support:support-core-ui:26.1.0@aar
+--- com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:26.1.0@aar
+--- com.android.support:support-compat:26.1.0@aar
+--- com.android.support:support-annotations:26.1.0@jar
+--- javax.inject:javax.inject:1@jar
+--- androidx.fragment:fragment:1.0.0-alpha1@aar
+--- androidx.legacy:legacy-support-core-ui:1.0.0-alpha1@aar
+--- androidx.legacy:legacy-support-core-utils:1.0.0-alpha1@aar
+--- androidx.media:media:1.0.0-alpha1@aar
+--- androidx.transition:transition:1.0.0-alpha1@aar
+--- androidx.loader:loader:1.0.0-alpha1@aar
+--- androidx.viewpager:viewpager:1.0.0-alpha1@aar
+--- androidx.coordinatorlayout:coordinatorlayout:1.0.0-alpha1@aar
+--- androidx.drawerlayout:drawerlayout:1.0.0-alpha1@aar
+--- androidx.slidingpanelayout:slidingpanelayout:1.0.0-alpha1@aar
+--- androidx.customview:customview:1.0.0-alpha1@aar
+--- androidx.swiperefreshlayout:swiperefreshlayout:1.0.0-alpha1@aar
+--- androidx.asynclayoutinflater:asynclayoutinflater:1.0.0-alpha1@aar
+--- androidx.core:core:1.0.0-alpha1@aar
+--- androidx.collection:collection:1.0.0-alpha1@jar
+--- androidx.cursoradapter:cursoradapter:1.0.0-alpha1@aar
+--- androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-process:2.0.0-alpha1@aar
+--- androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-service:2.0.0-alpha1@aar
+--- androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime:2.0.0-alpha1@aar
+--- androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata:2.0.0-alpha1@aar
+--- androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-core:2.0.0-alpha1@aar
+--- androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-common:2.0.0-alpha1@jar
+--- androidx.arch.core:core-runtime:2.0.0-alpha1@aar
+--- androidx.arch.core:core-common:2.0.0-alpha1@jar
+--- androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel:2.0.0-alpha1@aar
+--- androidx.documentfile:documentfile:1.0.0-alpha1@aar
+--- androidx.localbroadcastmanager:localbroadcastmanager:1.0.0-alpha1@aar
+--- androidx.print:print:1.0.0-alpha1@aar
+--- androidx.interpolator:interpolator:1.0.0-alpha1@aar
+--- androidx.annotation:annotation:1.0.0-alpha1@jar
+--- com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.0-beta1@aar
+--- com.github.akarnokd:rxjava2-extensions:0.15.2@jar
+--- io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.0.1@aar
+--- io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.0.6@jar
+--- org.reactivestreams:reactive-streams:1.0.0@jar
+--- com.squareup.moshi:moshi:1.5.0@jar
+--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect:1.1.1@jar
+--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.2.41@jar
+--- com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-analyzer:1.5.1@jar
+--- com.crashlytics.sdk.android:beta:1.2.5@aar
+--- com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics-core:2.3.17@aar
+--- com.crashlytics.sdk.android:answers:1.3.13@aar
+--- io.fabric.sdk.android:fabric:1.3.17@aar
+--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-base:15.0.2@aar
+--- com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout-solver:1.1.0-beta1@jar
+--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth-license:11.4.2@aar
+--- com.squareup.haha:haha:2.0.3@jar
+--- com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-watcher:1.5.1@jar
+--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth-api-phone-license:11.4.2@aar
+--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth-base-license:11.4.2@aar
+--- com.squareup.okio:okio:1.13.0@jar
+--- org.jetbrains:annotations:13.0@jar
+--- android.arch.lifecycle:runtime:1.0.0@aar
+--- android.arch.lifecycle:common:1.0.0@jar
\--- android.arch.core:common:1.0.0@jar
```

The question is: is there a way for me to know which dependency is importing the support library apart from checking the `build.gradle`:

```
  buildscript {
      repositories {
          maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
          mavenCentral()
          google()
      }
      dependencies {
          classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.25.4'
      }
  }

  repositories {
      mavenCentral()
      maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
      maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }
  }

  apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
  apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
  apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
  apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'
  apply plugin: 'io.fabric'
  apply plugin: 'realm-android'

  android {
      def versionMajor = 0
      def versionMinor = 1
      def versionPatch = 0

      compileSdkVersion 'android-P'
      compileOptions {
          targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
          sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
          defaultConfig {
              applicationId "org.appid"
              versionName "${versionMajor}.${versionMinor}.${versionPatch}"
              versionCode versionMajor * 10000
              + versionMinor * 100
              + versionPatch

              minSdkVersion 19
              targetSdkVersion 27

              dexOptions {
                  preDexLibraries = false
                  javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
              }
          }
      }

      buildTypes {
          release {
              debuggable false
              minifyEnabled true
              zipAlignEnabled true
              renderscriptDebuggable false
              proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
              signingConfig signingConfigs.release
              javaCompileOptions.annotationProcessorOptions.arguments['butterknife.debuggable'] = 'false'
              resValue "string", "app_version", "${defaultConfig.versionName}"
          }
          debug {
              versionNameSuffix "_dev"
              resValue "string", "app_version", "${defaultConfig.versionName}${versionNameSuffix}"
              debuggable true
              signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
              minifyEnabled false
          }
      }
  }

  def jsr250_api = '1.0'
  def androidxVersion = '1.0.0-alpha1'
  def lifecycle_runtime = '2.0.0-alpha1'
  def daggerVer = '2.16'
  def rxbinding = '2.0.0'
  def rxbus2 = '0.1'
  def retrofit2 = '2.2.0'
  def okhttp3 = '3.4.1'
  def firebase = '15.0.0'
  def firebase_database = '15.0.1'
  def firebaseConfig = '15.0.2'
  def firebase_ui_auth = '3.1.0'
  def butter_knife = '8.8.1'
  def leak_canary = '1.5.1'
  def persistent_cookie_jar = 'v1.0.1'
  def joda_time = '2.5'
  def timber = '4.3.1'
  def justified_text_view = '1.0'
  def crashlytics = '2.6.8@aar'
  def hamcrestVersion = '1.3'
  def espresso_core = '3.1.0-alpha1'
  def mockitoKotlinVersion       = '1.5.0'
  def mockitoKotlinInlineVersion = '2.13.0' // to allow testing final classes
  def junit = '4.12'

  dependencies {
      kapt "com.google.dagger:dagger-android-processor:$daggerVer"
      implementation "com.google.dagger:dagger-android:$daggerVer"
      kapt "com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:$daggerVer"

      implementation "androidx.appcompat:appcompat:$androidxVersion"
      implementation "androidx.cardview:cardview:$androidxVersion"
      implementation "androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:$androidxVersion"
      implementation "androidx.gridlayout:gridlayout:$androidxVersion"
      implementation "androidx.preference:preference:$androidxVersion"
      implementation "androidx.vectordrawable:vectordrawable:$androidxVersion"
      implementation "androidx.palette:palette:$androidxVersion"
      implementation "com.google.android.material:material:$androidxVersion"

      implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:$firebase"
      implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-config:$firebaseConfig"
      implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-database:$firebase_database"
      implementation "com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:$firebase_ui_auth"
      implementation "com.jakewharton.rxbinding2:rxbinding:$rxbinding"
      implementation "com.jakewharton.rxrelay2:rxrelay:$rxbinding"

      implementation "joda-time:joda-time:$joda_time"
      implementation "com.jakewharton.timber:timber:$timber"
      implementation "com.uncopt:android.justified:$justified_text_view"

      implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-common-java8:$lifecycle_runtime"
      kapt "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-compiler:$lifecycle_runtime"
      implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:$lifecycle_runtime"
      testImplementation "androidx.arch.core:core-testing:$lifecycle_runtime"

      //To use LiveData with ReactiveStreams API
      implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-reactivestreams:$lifecycle_runtime"
      implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:$retrofit2"
      implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava2:$retrofit2"
      implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-moshi:$retrofit2"
      implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-scalars:$retrofit2"
      implementation "com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:$okhttp3"
      implementation "com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp-urlconnection:$okhttp3"
      implementation "com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:$okhttp3"
      implementation "com.github.franmontiel:PersistentCookieJar:$persistent_cookie_jar"
      implementation 'com.squareup.moshi:moshi-kotlin:1.5.0'
      implementation "com.github.MFlisar:RxBus2:$rxbus2"
      kapt "com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:$butter_knife"
      implementation "com.jakewharton:butterknife:$butter_knife"
      implementation "com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android:$leak_canary"
      releaseImplementation "com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android-no-op:$leak_canary"
      testImplementation "com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android-no-op:$leak_canary"
      compileOnly "javax.annotation:jsr250-api:$jsr250_api"
      implementation("com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:$crashlytics") {
          transitive = true
      }
      implementation 'com.f2prateek.rx.preferences2:rx-preferences:2.0.0-RC2'
      implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
      testImplementation "junit:junit:$junit"
      testImplementation "com.nhaarman:mockito-kotlin:$mockitoKotlinVersion"
      testImplementation "org.mockito:mockito-inline:$mockitoKotlinInlineVersion"
      testImplementation "org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:$hamcrestVersion"
      testImplementation "org.hamcrest:hamcrest-library:$hamcrestVersion"
      testImplementation "org.hamcrest:hamcrest-integration:$hamcrestVersion"
      androidTestImplementation("androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:$espresso_core", {
          exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
      })
  }

  androidExtensions {
      experimental = true
  }

  apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

  android.packagingOptions {
      exclude 'LICENSE.txt'
      exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
      exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
      exclude 'META-INF/rxjava.properties'
  }

  configurations.all {
      resolutionStrategy.force 'com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:1.3.9'
  }
```

Comment: You can use `./gradlew tasks --all` to find out which tasks you have. Among them there will be something like `yourproject:dependencies`, which you can run to get dependency tree like this: `./gradlew yourproject:dependencies`

Can you find from where you get that support-v4 library? I'm struggling with "cannot find support-v4-1.0.0-alpha1.aar"

Comment: See my answer for this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51232581/androidx-android-support-v4-app-inotificationsidechannelstub/51392834#51392834. (TL;DR no fix until google does something)

Answer (score 89, accepted):

I have very similar problem and in my case solution is add in `gradle.properties` this two lines:

```
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
```

I hope it will help.

Comment: My problem arise when using Flutter with the google map plugin, and this solution worked. Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

You can use `./gradlew tasks --all` to find out which tasks you have. Among them there will be something like `yourproject:dependencies`, which you can run to get dependency tree like this:

```
./gradlew yourproject:dependencies
```

Comment: isn't it './gradlew androidDependencies'? I have already run it and I could see that there are depenencies from support libs even if I'm not importing them directly

Comment: @kingston , no, these are two different things (don't ask me how or what, I'm not android developer)

Answer (score 6):

Try to **MIGRATE** to **ANDROIDX** from the following path in Android Studio:

> (Refactor>Migrate to AndroidX...)

Answer (score 4):

I got the same issue while adding,

```
dataBinding {
    enabled = true
}
```

in app.gradle module.
My gradle dependency is as:

```
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.0-alpha3'
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.2'
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0-alpha3'
```

When I changed to,

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-alpha3'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'
```

I could get rid out of the error while running the project.

Comment: OK but you are not using androidx. My app works too, if I don't switch to androidx

Comment: I got the same error while moved to androidx. Couldn't find a solution with androidx.

Answer (score 1):

just marge dependency on AndroidX Library.

Example: app/build.gradle:

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
```

to:

```
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.0'
implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
```

Than rebuild again, shows many errors. just comment out these old libraries. re-import android x library package. 
Example below:
[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Marge AndroidX: https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate

I hope to solve your problem.

Answer (score -2):

I think the problem is due to conflicting dependencies. In my case, the problem went away when I removed androidx dependency.

From:

`dependencies {
    implementation "androidx.work:work-runtime:2.1.0"
}`

To:
`dependencies {
    implementation "android.arch.work:work-runtime:1.0.1"
}`

This may not be possible if you are too dependendent on androidx.