# androidx android.support.v4.app.INotificationSideChannel$Stub

Tags: android, androidx

I was working with android jetback after add recycle view with androidx  and databinding and live datait started showing
`android.support.v4.app.INotificationSideChannel$Stub`.
I have tried a lot of solutions so far but nothing has helped. Why does it show this error when I am not using any support library and what can I do to solve it?
update :
after retracing my steps i removed the data binding and every thing worked fine can any one explain
Here is my gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'


android {
compileSdkVersion 28
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.ahmedmubarak.pixeapp"
    minSdkVersion 19
    targetSdkVersion 27
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"

}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'),       'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
dataBinding {
    enabled = true
}
}

dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation"org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.0-beta01'
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.2'
implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.0.0-beta01'
implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0-beta01'
implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.0.0-beta01'
implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.0'
implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'

}
```

Answer (score 4):

I added this to `build.gradle` to remove the error

```
configurations {
    implementation {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-v4'
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, I predict that you'll see a new error (at run-time) like this:
`java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of:`

I believe this is an AndroidX issue that occurs with lots of support libraries that have yet to be updated to support AndroidX.

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar problem. In my case, it was because I am using Glide library and androidx. This solution works for me:

1. Set enableJetifier value to `true`
2. Update Gradle build tool to 3.3.0-alpha08 with Gradle version 4.9

[source](https://github.com/bumptech/glide/issues/3185)