# assembleDebug keeps on failing

Tags: android, dart, flutter

My app was working fine up until the new flutter update 1.0, since then I've been seeing problems the most significant being that my app won't run every time I run it fails at "assembleDebug". I've restarted the project 4 times and same problem occurs. note this is note because i'm refactoring for android x

I've restarted the project,
Change my complileSDK to 28

build.gradle(android)

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
      google()
      jcenter()
   }
 dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'
 }
}
 allprojects {
     repositories {
        google()
      jcenter()
   }
}
rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects 
 {
   project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
 }
 subprojects {
   project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
 }

 task clean(type: Delete) {
 delete rootProject.buildDir
}

subprojects {
  project.configurations.all {
     resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { details ->
        if (details.requested.group == 'com.android.support'
                && !details.requested.name.contains('multidex') ) {
            details.useVersion "27.1.0"
        }
    }
  }
}
```

build.gradle(app)

```
  def localProperties = new Properties()
  def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
  if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
  localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
    localProperties.load(reader)
  }
}

 def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
 if (flutterRoot == null) {
 throw new GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with
  flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
 }

  def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty   ('flutter.versionCode')
   if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
   flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"

   android {
   compileSdkVersion 28

   lintOptions {
     disable 'InvalidPackage'
  }

   defaultConfig {
       // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID       (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.rookieplays.main24hours"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }
  }

flutter {
    source '../..'
 }

 dependencies {
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-    core:3.0.2'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Output:

```
Launching lib\main.dart on Android SDK built for x86 in debug mode...
Initializing gradle...
Resolving dependencies...
Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedResFolders(FileCollection)
registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedResFolders(FileCollection)
registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedResFolders(FileCollection)
registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedResFolders(FileCollection)
registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedResFolders(FileCollection)
Note: E:\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\firebase_auth-0.6.6\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\firebaseauth\FirebaseAuthPlugin.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: E:\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\firebase_auth-0.6.6\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\firebaseauth\FirebaseAuthPlugin.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
Note: E:\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\firebase_core-0.2.5+1\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\firebase\core\FirebaseCorePlugin.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
D8: Program type already present: android.support.v4.os.ResultReceiver$MyResultReceiver

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDebug'.
> com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Error while merging dex archives: C:\Users\Ali\AndroidStudioProjects\tfh\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\2.jar, C:\Users\Ali\AndroidStudioProjects\tfh\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\3.jar, C:\Users\Ali\AndroidStudioProjects\tfh\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\4.jar, C:\Users\Ali\AndroidStudioProjects\tfh\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\5.jar, C:\Users\Ali\AndroidStudioProjects\tfh\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\6.jar, C:\Users\Ali\AndroidStudioProjects\tfh\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\7.jar, C:\Users\Ali\AndroidStudioProjects\tfh\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\8.jar, C:\Users\Ali\AndroidStudioProjects\tfh\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\9.jar, C:\Users\Ali\AndroidStudioProjects\tfh\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\10.jar, C:\Users\Ali\AndroidStudioProjects\tfh\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\11.jar, C:\Users\Ali\AndroidStudioProjects\tfh\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\12.jar, C:\Users\Ali\AndroidStudioProjects\tfh\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\13.jar, C:\Users\Ali\AndroidStudioProjects\tfh\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\14.jar, C:\Users\Ali\AndroidStudioProjects\tfh\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\15.jar, C:\Users\Ali\AndroidStudioProjects\tfh\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\16.jar, C:\Users\Ali\AndroidStudioProjects\tfh\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\17.jar, C:\Users\Ali\AndroidStudioProjects\tfh\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\18.jar, C:\Users\Ali\AndroidStudioProjects\tfh\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\19.jar, C:\Users\Ali\AndroidStudioProjects\tfh\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\20.jar, C:\Users\Ali\AndroidStudioProjects\tfh\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\21.jar, C:\Users\Ali\AndroidStudioProjects\tfh\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\22.jar, C:\Users\Ali\AndroidStudioProjects\tfh\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\23.jar, C:\Users\Ali\AndroidStudioProjects\tfh\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\24.jar, C:\Users\Ali\AndroidStudioProjects\tfh\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\25.jar, C:\Users\Ali\AndroidStudioProjects\tfh\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\26.jar, C:\Users\Ali\AndroidStudioProjects\tfh\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\28.jar, C:\Users\Ali\AndroidStudioProjects\tfh\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\29.jar, C:\Users\Ali\AndroidStudioProjects\tfh\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\30.jar, C:\Users\Ali\AndroidStudioProjects\tfh\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\33.jar, C:\Users\Ali\AndroidStudioProjects\tfh\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\34.jar, C:\Users\Ali\AndroidStudioProjects\tfh\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\35.jar, C:\Users\Ali\AndroidStudioProjects\tfh\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\36.jar, C:\Users\Ali\AndroidStudioProjects\tfh\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\37.jar, C:\Users\Ali\AndroidStudioProjects\tfh\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\38.jar, C:\Users\Ali\AndroidStudioProjects\tfh\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\39.jar, C:\Users\Ali\AndroidStudioProjects\tfh\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\40.jar, C:\Users\Ali\AndroidStudioProjects\tfh\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\41.jar, C:\Users\Ali\AndroidStudioProjects\tfh\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\42.jar, C:\Users\Ali\AndroidStudioProjects\tfh\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\44.jar, C:\Users\Ali\AndroidStudioProjects\tfh\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\45.jar, C:\Users\Ali\AndroidStudioProjects\tfh\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\46.jar, C:\Users\Ali\AndroidStudioProjects\tfh\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\47.jar, C:\Users\Ali\AndroidStudioProjects\tfh\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\48.jar, C:\Users\Ali\AndroidStudioProjects\tfh\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\49.jar, C:\Users\Ali\AndroidStudioProjects\tfh\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\50.jar, C:\Users\Ali\AndroidStudioProjects\tfh\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\51.jar, C:\Users\Ali\AndroidStudioProjects\tfh\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\52.jar, C:\Users\Ali\AndroidStudioProjects\tfh\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\53.jar, C:\Users\Ali\AndroidStudioProjects\tfh\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\55.jar, C:\Users\Ali\AndroidStudioProjects\tfh\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\56.jar, C:\Users\Ali\AndroidStudioProjects\tfh\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\57.jar, C:\Users\Ali\AndroidStudioProjects\tfh\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\58.jar, C:\Users\Ali\AndroidStudioProjects\tfh\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\59.jar, C:\Users\Ali\AndroidStudioProjects\tfh\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\60.jar, C:\Users\Ali\AndroidStudioProjects\tfh\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\61.jar, C:\Users\Ali\AndroidStudioProjects\tfh\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\62.jar, C:\Users\Ali\AndroidStudioProjects\tfh\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\65.jar, C:\Users\Ali\AndroidStudioProjects\tfh\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\66.jar, C:\Users\Ali\AndroidStudioProjects\tfh\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\67.jar, C:\Users\Ali\AndroidStudioProjects\tfh\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\68.jar, C:\Users\Ali\AndroidStudioProjects\tfh\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\69.jar, C:\Users\Ali\AndroidStudioProjects\tfh\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\70.jar, C:\Users\Ali\AndroidStudioProjects\tfh\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\71.jar, C:\Users\Ali\AndroidStudioProjects\tfh\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\72.jar, C:\Users\Ali\AndroidStudioProjects\tfh\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\73.jar, C:\Users\Ali\AndroidStudioProjects\tfh\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\74.jar, C:\Users\Ali\AndroidStudioProjects\tfh\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\75.jar, C:\Users\Ali\AndroidStudioProjects\tfh\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\76.jar, C:\Users\Ali\AndroidStudioProjects\tfh\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\77.jar, C:\Users\Ali\AndroidStudioProjects\tfh\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\78.jar, C:\Users\Ali\AndroidStudioProjects\tfh\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\79.jar, C:\Users\Ali\AndroidStudioProjects\tfh\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\80.jar, C:\Users\Ali\AndroidStudioProjects\tfh\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\81.jar, C:\Users\Ali\AndroidStudioProjects\tfh\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\82.jar, C:\Users\Ali\AndroidStudioProjects\tfh\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\83.jar, C:\Users\Ali\AndroidStudioProjects\tfh\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\84.jar, C:\Users\Ali\AndroidStudioProjects\tfh\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\85.jar, C:\Users\Ali\AndroidStudioProjects\tfh\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\86.jar, C:\Users\Ali\AndroidStudioProjects\tfh\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\87.jar, C:\Users\Ali\AndroidStudioProjects\tfh\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\88.jar, C:\Users\Ali\AndroidStudioProjects\tfh\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\89.jar, C:\Users\Ali\AndroidStudioProjects\tfh\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\90.jar, C:\Users\Ali\AndroidStudioProjects\tfh\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\91.jar, C:\Users\Ali\AndroidStudioProjects\tfh\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\92.jar, C:\Users\Ali\AndroidStudioProjects\tfh\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\93.jar, C:\Users\Ali\AndroidStudioProjects\tfh\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\94.jar, C:\Users\Ali\AndroidStudioProjects\tfh\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\96.jar, C:\Users\Ali\AndroidStudioProjects\tfh\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\97.jar, C:\Users\Ali\AndroidStudioProjects\tfh\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\98.jar, C:\Users\Ali\AndroidStudioProjects\tfh\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\99.jar, C:\Users\Ali\AndroidStudioProjects\tfh\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\100.jar, C:\Users\Ali\AndroidStudioProjects\tfh\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\101.jar, C:\Users\Ali\AndroidStudioProjects\tfh\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\102.jar, C:\Users\Ali\AndroidStudioProjects\tfh\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\103.jar, C:\Users\Ali\AndroidStudioProjects\tfh\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\104.jar, C:\Users\Ali\AndroidStudioProjects\tfh\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\105.jar, C:\Users\Ali\AndroidStudioProjects\tfh\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\106.jar, C:\Users\Ali\AndroidStudioProjects\tfh\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\107.jar, C:\Users\Ali\AndroidStudioProjects\tfh\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\108.jar, C:\Users\Ali\AndroidStudioProjects\tfh\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\109.jar, C:\Users\Ali\AndroidStudioProjects\tfh\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\110.jar, C:\Users\Ali\AndroidStudioProjects\tfh\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\111.jar, C:\Users\Ali\AndroidStudioProjects\tfh\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\112.jar, C:\Users\Ali\AndroidStudioProjects\tfh\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\113.jar, C:\Users\Ali\AndroidStudioProjects\tfh\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\114.jar, C:\Users\Ali\AndroidStudioProjects\tfh\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\115.jar, C:\Users\Ali\AndroidStudioProjects\tfh\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\116.jar, C:\Users\Ali\AndroidStudioProjects\tfh\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\117.jar, C:\Users\Ali\AndroidStudioProjects\tfh\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\118.jar, C:\Users\Ali\AndroidStudioProjects\tfh\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\119.jar, C:\Users\Ali\AndroidStudioProjects\tfh\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\120.jar, C:\Users\Ali\AndroidStudioProjects\tfh\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\121.jar, C:\Users\Ali\AndroidStudioProjects\tfh\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\122.jar, C:\Users\Ali\AndroidStudioProjects\tfh\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\123.jar, C:\Users\Ali\AndroidStudioProjects\tfh\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\124.jar, C:\Users\Ali\AndroidStudioProjects\tfh\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\125.jar, C:\Users\Ali\AndroidStudioProjects\tfh\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\126.jar, C:\Users\Ali\AndroidStudioProjects\tfh\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\127.jar, C:\Users\Ali\AndroidStudioProjects\tfh\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\128.jar, C:\Users\Ali\AndroidStudioProjects\tfh\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\129.jar, C:\Users\Ali\AndroidStudioProjects\tfh\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\130.jar, C:\Users\Ali\AndroidStudioProjects\tfh\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\131.jar, C:\Users\Ali\AndroidStudioProjects\tfh\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\132.jar, C:\Users\Ali\AndroidStudioProjects\tfh\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\133.jar, C:\Users\Ali\AndroidStudioProjects\tfh\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\134.jar, C:\Users\Ali\AndroidStudioProjects\tfh\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\135.jar, C:\Users\Ali\AndroidStudioProjects\tfh\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\136.jar, C:\Users\Ali\AndroidStudioProjects\tfh\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\137.jar, C:\Users\Ali\AndroidStudioProjects\tfh\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\138.jar, C:\Users\Ali\AndroidStudioProjects\tfh\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\139.jar, C:\Users\Ali\AndroidStudioProjects\tfh\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\140.jar, C:\Users\Ali\AndroidStudioProjects\tfh\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\141.jar, C:\Users\Ali\AndroidStudioProjects\tfh\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\142.jar, C:\Users\Ali\AndroidStudioProjects\tfh\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\143.jar, C:\Users\Ali\AndroidStudioProjects\tfh\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\144.jar, C:\Users\Ali\AndroidStudioProjects\tfh\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\145.jar, C:\Users\Ali\AndroidStudioProjects\tfh\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\146.jar, C:\Users\Ali\AndroidStudioProjects\tfh\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\147.jar, C:\Users\Ali\AndroidStudioProjects\tfh\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\148.jar, C:\Users\Ali\AndroidStudioProjects\tfh\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\149.jar, C:\Users\Ali\AndroidStudioProjects\tfh\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\150.jar, C:\Users\Ali\AndroidStudioProjects\tfh\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\151.jar, C:\Users\Ali\AndroidStudioProjects\tfh\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\152.jar, C:\Users\Ali\AndroidStudioProjects\tfh\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\153.jar, C:\Users\Ali\AndroidStudioProjects\tfh\build\app\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\154.jar
  Learn how to resolve the issue at https://developer.android.com/studio/build/dependencies#duplicate_classes.
  Program type already present: android.support.v4.os.ResultReceiver$MyResultReceiver

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 3m 4s
Finished with error: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

Comment: This sounds like an android specific issue. Check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47079113/android-studio-3-0-execution-failed-for-task-unable-to-merge-dex). I'm guessing it might be because you changed compileSDK version to 28, but didn't change `details.useVersion "27.1.0"`. But also setting multiDexEnabled to true might help - it looks like your apk is quite large...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Program type already present: android.support.v4.os.ResultReceiver$MyResultReceiver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50676100/program-type-already-present-android-support-v4-os-resultreceivermyresultrecei). it's `details.useVersion "28.0.0"`.