# How to fix unable merge with dex in ionic?

Tags: android, ionic-framework, build, ionic3

I’m getting issue follow while taking android build.

**Execution failed for task ':app:transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDebug’**

> Task :CordovaLib:compileDebugShaders UP-TO-DATE
>   Task :CordovaLib:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
>   Task :CordovaLib:packageDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
>   Task :app:mergeDebugAssets
>   Task :app:validateSigningDebug UP-TO-DATE
>   Task :app:signingConfigWriterDebug UP-TO-DATE
>   Task :app:transformClassesWithDexBuilderForDebug UP-TO-DATE
>
> Task :app:transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDebug FAILED
>   D8: Program type already present: android.support.v4.os.ResultReceiver$MyResultReceiver

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDebug'.

  > com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Error while merging dex archives: 
  >   Learn how to resolve the issue at https://developer.android.com/studio/build/dependencies#duplicate_classes.
  >   Program type already present: android.support.v4.os.ResultReceiver$MyResultReceiver
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 22s
35 actionable tasks: 3 executed, 32 up-to-date
/Users/panmoh/Documents/mobile-app/platforms/android/gradlew: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
D8: Program type already present: android.support.v4.os.ResultReceiver$MyResultReceiver

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDebug'.

  > com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Error while merging dex archives: 
  >   Learn how to resolve the issue at https://developer.android.com/studio/build/dependencies#duplicate_classes.
  >   Program type already present: android.support.v4.os.ResultReceiver$MyResultReceiver
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 22s
[ERROR] An error occurred while running subprocess cordova.

```
    cordova build android exited with exit code 1.

    Re-running this command with the --verbose flag may provide more information.
```

**Note : I tried `cordova clean android` and remove and add android platfoem as well**

Answer (score 6):

**To fix this issue for those using Phonegap/Cordova**

- Install the “cordova-plugin-androidx” plugin

  `cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-androidx`
- Install “cordova-plugin-androidx-adapter” plugin

  `cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-androidx-adapter`
- Add these lines in your gradle.properties :

  `android.useAndroidX=true
  android.enableJetifier=true`

After this, make a build: `cordova -d build android` and check the result

Answer (score 1):

solutions is following : make sure the following :

- Upgrade com.android.tools.build:gradle to v3.2.1 or later.
- Upgrade compileSdkVersion to 28 or later. . Update your app to use
- Jetpack (AndroidX); follow the instructions in Migrating to AndroidX.

For Cordova/Ionic project just add the following plugins:

https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-plugin-androidx
https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-plugin-androidx-adapter
Those plugins will fix build error. and everything will work fine :)..

Comment: I don't use cordova-plugin-androidx in my project

Comment: @Mohanraj I Think If you add this plugin will fix your problem  in my case it fix all version conflict and build errors

Answer (score 0):

The solution accepted here is the true solution. I stuck with this issue for a week and than on last weekend i decided no matter what happens a'll find solution for it.

[All credit goes to this person named (**ProdoElmit**) who answered it here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50676100/program-type-already-present-android-support-v4-os-resultreceivermyresultrecei)

Attaching screenshots for above solution to make it easier to follow:
[image: gradlew.bat tasks --all]

[image: gradlew.bat yourproject:dependencies] Here my project name was **app**

In my case it was FCM which was using androidx and causing this issue. Hope this will help someone to resolve their issue as well.
[image]