# "Program type already present" after updating all of my google lib

Tags: build.gradle, androidx, receiver

When I updated all of my google lib I get the error: `Program type already present: android.support.v4.os.ResultReceiver$MyResultReceiver`, but I don't want to update to androidx, is there another solution?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Program type already present: android.support.v4.os.ResultReceiver$MyResultReceiver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50676100/program-type-already-present-android-support-v4-os-resultreceivermyresultrecei)

Comment: yeah i sure that is reason but i don't know what lib contains that package